# Methods and functions from multiple screens

Tags: python, methods, kivy

How to ensure functions and methods are accessible on multiple screens?
I would like to use a calculation method that can be used with inputs from my camera screen and from my input screen. Where does the method go in the main.py file? I was thinking under ScreenSwitch class.

main.py

```
import math
import time

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

Builder.load_file('camera.kv')

class ScreenSwitch(ScreenManager):
    pass
class CameraScreen(Screen):
    def capture(self):
        cam = self.ids.camera
        timestamp = time.strftime(("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"))
        cam.export_to_png("IMG_{}.png".format(timestamp))

class DisplayScreen(Screen):
    pass
class SettingScreen(Screen):
    pass

class tipbotApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "tipBot                              version: 1"


tipbotApp().run()
```

tipbot.kv

```
ScreenSwitch:
    CameraScreen:
    DisplayScreen:
    SettingScreen:
```

camera.kv

```
<CameraScreen>:
    name: 'camera'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Camera:
            id: camera
            resolution: (600, 480)
            play: False

        Button:
            id: capture
            text: "Capture"
            size_hint_y: None
        Button:
            id: cameramanual
            text: "Manual Entry"
            size_hint_y: None
        Button:
            id: camerasettings
            text: "Settings"
            size_hint_y: None
```

Comment: If you put the method in your `App`, you can access it from anywhere using `App.get_running_app()` in `py` or by using `app` in `kv`.

Comment: In the case of the capture method, I can move it under the class tipbotApp(App) and use the on_release  app.capture() to take a picture with the kivy camera.